# How to copy all images in a helm chart offline

Tags: kubernetes, isolated-network, helm

I have helm\tiller installed on my on-prem Kubernetes deployment which is isolated from the internet.
I'm trying to copy some helm charts to my isolated network and I'm finding the process of understanding which container images I need to download quite difficult, for example, Prometheus chart requires 6 images if not more.

Does anyone know if there is an automated process of retrieving chart images automatic?

I understand that after downloading all the images I have to manually go to each chart values file and change the paths to my local repositories.

Comment: first download the images on the nodes using docker pull, and to deploy your local chart you can use --set image...., you need to check the values.yaml

Comment: Yes i know that part, it just very hard to do that to a large helm chart with many sub-charts and images especially if your working in an airgap network.

Comment: Was the issue solved, or you sill facing it?